# Best practices for boolean methods in DAO level

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dao

What is the best practices for implementing method that retrieve **boolean value** in DAO level (Hibernate/JPA).

1. Return list of values and check on null or isEmpty() or
2. Return boolean at once

(*Code is fictional and there is no any similarity in real world*)

```java
@Repository
public interface UserDao  {

    User getUsersById(List<Integer> userIds);

    boolean isContainsUsers(List<Integer> userIds);
}

@Service
public class UserService{

    @Autowired 
    UserDao userDao;

    public void doBusinessLogicWithUser(List<Integer> userIds){

       boolean isContainsUsers = userDao.getUserById(userIds).isEmpty();

       boolean isContainsUsers = userDao.isContainsUsers(userIds);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning boolean at once should work faster, because you can write a good query, for instance:

```
select count(*) != 0 from table t where t.id in :ids
```

On the other hand, when you return a collection, it should firstly pass a lot of values through network and map all properties to your entity class - these operations is time consuming

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
If I correct understood you it's better to use this method:
**boolean isContainsUsers()**